# A RenderFlex expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverPadding

Tags: flutter, mobile

I want to create a gridview insid container because my parent i use custom scrollview

```
CustomScrollView(
              primary: false,
              controller: _scrollController,
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 230,
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 60,
                              height: 10,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

and i have error message like this :

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Container(bg: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffffffff), borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0), topRight: Radius.circular(20.0))), constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=890.3)):
A RenderFlex expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverPadding.

What do I have to do in this situation?